Name of partition in luks device
Ubuntu 20.04
I have luks device, and made some partitions on it.
When I mount it to encrypt1,
I can get partition devices by followed command
fdisk -l|grep "/dev/mapper/encrypt1"
/dev/mapper/encrypt1p1    2048  780287  778240  380M Linux filesystem
/dev/mapper/encrypt1p2  780288 1562623  782336  382M Linux filesystem
/dev/mapper/encrypt1p3 1562624 2342911  780288  381M Linux filesystem

BUT IN SOME CASE(IN SNAP APP), THE RESULT IS
/dev/mapper/encrypt1-part1    2048  780287  778240  380M Linux filesystem
/dev/mapper/encrypt1-part2  780288 1562623  782336  382M Linux filesystem
/dev/mapper/encrypt1-part3 1562624 2342911  780288  381M Linux filesystem

Who the rule of name of partitions in luks device? And why it was changed in different case?
Thank you

Please edit the question and add the version of Ubuntu being used.
